# load content to modal after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to load content to a result div that is located inside a modal-body after form is submitted and after modal is shown but i can't figure out the problem. when i want to load content to a result div outside modal it works, but when i use the result div inside a modal it doesn't.
this is my code so far:

html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12"> 
        <div class="row">            
                    <div id="form-content">
            <form method="post" id="reg-form" autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <div id="monetarylayout" class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control number" type="text" value="0" name="subjectvalue" id="txt_subjectvalue">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>

                </div>
                        <input class="form-control number" type="text" value="0" name="coinquantity" id="txt_coinquantity" style="display:none"> <!--just to make the form post work-->


        </form>
                </div>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                                    <div id="result"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        // submit form using $.ajax() method

        $('#reg-form').submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission

            $.ajax({
                url: 'testcontroller.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize() // it will serialize the form data
            })
            .done(function(data){
                        $('#myModal').modal(), function() {
                        // do something when the modal is shown    
                            $('#result').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                        }


            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');    
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: i wanted to add more code but stackoverflow didn't allow :(

Comment: i managed to add more code :)

Answer (score 0):

i figured out myself. i should have added these attributes to my form button:

```
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">submit</button>
```

and edited this function as follows:

```
.done(function (data) {

                        $('#result').fadeIn('slow').html(data);

                    })
```